# Can one open another application within a javaFX frame?

Tags: java, javafx, desktop-application

I am currently working on a desktop application in which one can generate a responsive website for documentation (java-doc like) by providing nothing more than a simple word document.

I currently have a prototype working in which I select for styles on certain paragraphs to determine its function and how it should be transformed to a correct HTML representation. I also found a way to dynamically link to certain section of the document. Everything is working however I would really like to combine the list of documents to generate, a preview of the to-be generated website and a text editor program in 1.

since this will be relying on word heavily I was wondering if Java FX provides a means to display an application such as word or openoffice within an internal frame. Much like how Java Fx's webview displays websites.

In an ideal situation it would look something like this:
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In short, no, there is no support in JavaFX to embed arbitrary native applications.

Comment: You cannot embed native applications easily in javaFx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alas, not possible in a plausible way.